# jQuery .attr() returning first(wrong) value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basicly I made a function that opens a page in a container `#page` when you click on `.menu` now the problem I'm having that it always shows the first `.menu data-open="url/url.html"`.

Let me explain this with the code:

I have 2 list items:

```
<li class="menu" data-open="pages/home.html"><a href="#"><div class="wrap">HOME</div></a></li>
<li class="menu" data-open="pages/services.html"><a href="#"><div class="wrap">SERVICES</div></a></li>
```

and I have `.click` function like this:

```
$("nav ul li.menu").click(function () {
    var url = $("nav ul li.menu").attr("data-open");
    console.log(url);
    loadPage(url)
});
```

Now the url **ALWAYS** returns from the **FIRST** list item no matter if I click on SERVICES.

Here's a GIF:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to reference the item that was clicked. Use:

```
var url = $(this).attr("data-open");
```

Instead of:

```
var url = $("nav ul li.menu").attr("data-open");
```

Comment: I would use `data('open')` instead of `attr()`, but the use of `this` will definitely solve the problem.

Comment: That's what happens when you don't do web development for a lot time. You forget things. And yes this is correct.

Comment: "web development for a long time" - typo and checked as a correct answer